# splunk inputcsv not recognized on windows 7

Tags: csv, splunk

I've been asked to do a proof of concept of importing a CSV file into splunk. So I've had to setup a Splunk Enterprise trial on my Windows 7 machine.

I've downloaded and installed the Splunk Enterprise MSI from the splunk site. And I've started the service successfully from the command line.

However when I try to import a CSV file it says the inputcsv subcommand can't be found.

```
splunk | inputcsv company-account-aws-billing-detailed-line-items-with-resources-and-tags-2017-10.csv
```

'inputcsv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

How can I correct this and import a CSV file into splunk on Windows 7?

Comment: You need to do inputcsv inside of Splunk search box, not from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Splunk Web, which can be found in http://localhost:8000/en-US/app/launcher/search 
(Port:8000 is used for default, change it if you have specified another) insert in the search

`splunk | inputcsv company-account-aws-billing-detailed-line-items-with-resources-and-tags-2017-10.csv`